# Correlation analysis in R - running a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation, pearson-correlation

I am trying to run some correlation analysis on my dataset. I would like to try several combinations using a for loop rather than writing an extreme long code. In particular, A very small sample of my data looks similar to this:

| Subject | nc_gm_mea | comp_gm_mean | nc_wm_mean | physicalscore | emotionalscore | fatiguescore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 76,435567 | 51,174758 | 54,8653634 | 2 | 0 | 6 |
| 2 | 57,499829 | 51,097165 | 63,856743 | 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 46,028136 | 33,198501 | 46,4356345 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 45,823601 | 35,9857 | 60,3452345 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

I would like to run correlations from data that are present here in column 2 (nc_gm_mean) with several combinations in a loop, i.e. using data from column 5 to 7 here.
Of course my table is bigger than the example here.. Anyone that can help me? Your help would be much appreciated.

> rcorr(correlation_data$nc_gm_mean, correlation_data$column5to7, type=c("pearson"))

Comment: Where does this `rcorr` function come from? Did you just mean `cor()`?

Comment: Probably `Hmisc`.

Comment: The `cor()` function will return a correlation matrix if provided a data frame as input, no loops needed. Is there some reason you can't use that?

Comment: Greetings! Typically it is recommended to provide a minimally reproducible dataset with your question. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can check out how to do this at this video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

loop is not needed as suggested by @
jdobres. You can compute as follows:
`stats::cor(correlation_data$nc_gm_mean, correlation_data[,5:7])`